# Override const function to modify a class variable in C++?

Tags: c++

While programming a personal software which I am developing in free time, I often feel the need for functionality in C++ so that only specific class variables in a function must be protected from modification.

**EDIT:** Following example is incorrect to explain the specific use case. Please refer the EDIT section at bottom of question instead. Keeping the code just to be in line with existing answers.

```
class Circle
{
  private:
    double radius;
    double area;

  public:
    void setRadius(double r);
    double getArea();
};

void Circle::setRadius(double r)
{
    radius = r;
}

double Circle::getArea()
{
    area = 3.142 * radius * radius;
    return area;
}
```

This is a very simple example just for the sake of explaining the question.
Now in `getArea()` I would like to prevent modification of `radius`.
But I cannot make `getArea() const` function because `area` is modified in it.

Some people might say that it is stupid programming on my part, but sometimes I find myself in such situations. This would really help prevent bugs during the development phase itself. If C++ has no way to do this, then please provide your valuable suggestions to tackle situations.

**EDIT:** In this example the computation involved in `getArea()` is very less because it depends on only `radius`, but sometimes it may depend on many variables.
Computing area in the setter function of each of these variables would result in unnecessary computation if all the variables need to be modified before getting the `area`. Calculating the value of `area` might be computationally intensive so storing the resulting value as a class variable is a good way to avoid recalculating if the getter of `area` is called multiple times. In such situations the following question is valid:

> I need to modify a class variable in a const function. How do I do
>   that?

Comment: In your example the `area` member serves **no purpose**. The computation is done every time `getArea` is called. For the example given the only logical response is that you should ditch the `area` data memeber since it has no purpose but does have some overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `area` a `mutable`, and mark `getArea() const`:

```
mutable double area;

double Circle::getArea() const 
{
    area = 3.142 * radius * radius;
    return area;
}
```

This is a common idiom for lazy initialization of data members, typically used when said data members are expensive to construct.

In this case it isn't clear that there is a benefit from caching `area` at all. You could sidestep the issue by removing the `area` data member, and returning the result

```
double Circle::getArea() const 
{
    return 3.142 * radius * radius;
}
```

Comment: That's not really the purpose of `mutable`.  `mutable` is meant for internal state that doesn't change the semantic meaning of a class (such as access statistics).  Because `area` has a fixed meaning with respect to `radius`, it should be updated when `radius` is updated.  **Edit:** although your point about lazy initialization is valid, fine.  Still seems like a bad use here.

Comment: @JoeZ not entirely. Lazy instantiation of data members is a common use-case, and it does not change the semantic meaning of the class. Granted, in this case, the connection with `radius` complicates things a bit.

Comment: I do agree with its use for lazy init, particularly for costly-to-init members.  I guess with the embedded programming I normally do, lazy init is usually a bad idea.  We actually want static, up-front initialization most of the time. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You should compute `area` inside of `setRadius()`, as the relationship between `area` and `radius` is fixed, and is a class-invariant.

Then `getArea()` simply needs to `return area;` and can be `const`.

This separation of duties (setters maintain class invariants, getters just return internal state) is the purpose of getters and setters.

**Edit:** Also note that in this example, you don't strictly need `area` to be a member of your class.  You could have defined your class as follows:

```
class Circle
{
  private:
    double radius;

  public:
    void setRadius(double r);
    double getArea() const;
};

void Circle::setRadius(double r)
{
    radius = r;
}

double Circle::getArea() const
{
    double area = 3.142 * radius * radius;
    return area;
}
```

By making `area` a local variable to the method rather than a class member, the method can remain `const`.

As others have noted, there is also a `mutable` keyword that you could have applied to `area`.  This is useful if modifying the variable doesn't change the outward meaning of the class.  It can be useful for lazy initialization, or maintaining internal statistics.

Usually, though, it's easier to reason about a class's properties and invariants if they're maintained up-front.

Comment: mutable directly answers the question but this is generally a better solution

Comment: @Joe Yes I agree. But this is a simple example! My classes typically have 10-20 variables and not everybody has a get...() and set...() function. Obviously I try to use get and set functions but there are exceptional cases...

Comment: @Cool_Coder : If some of those variables are just temporary variables used to compute a solution, they need not be class members.  For example, you do not need `area` as a member of your class.  You could have declared it as a local variable to `getArea()`, and then `getArea()` could still be `const`.

Comment: @Joe class Circle was just an example to explain the question! That is not a use case in my application.

Comment: @Cool_Coder : I understand that.  If you really have a large amount of internal state that isn't `const`, then perhaps trying to make your getter `const` is the wrong answer for that getter.  Usually, though, folks don't expect `getXXX` to modify the class.  (I will grant the lazy initialization case, particularly if the lazily-initialized members are expensive to initialize.)

Comment: @Cool_Coder:  For those member variables which do not have or need `(g|s)et()` member functions, why not just make those members public?

Comment: @JohnDibling would not that be breaking the encapsulation philosophy of C++?

Comment: @Cool_Coder : It would.  If they're not part of your interface (either as public members or via get/set methods), they _should_ remain private.  If they're costly to maintain, so you do lazy updates, then go ahead and modify them from methods that otherwise might be `const`.  If modifying them doesn't change the semantic value of the class, make the method `const` and the members `mutable`.  It all depends on what you're trying to do; much was compressed away from your example.

Comment: @Joe Z and John I have updated the question for a possible use case where it would be necessary to modify a class variable in a const function.

Comment: @Cool_Coder :  I'm back now, and I see your edit.  I believe the `mutable` keyword covers that case.  Another strategy is to rely on Has-A relationships:  An outer class manipulates inner classes through references or pointers; the method that does this can be `const` if it does not modify the outer class.

Answer (score 1):

> Some people might say that it is stupid programming on my part, but sometimes I find myself in such situations.

Yes, it is, and you shouldn't.

If you find you must cache such calculations, do it when the component factors are computed and *not* in a getter. (Frankly, in this case, I wouldn't store `area` at all.)

The `const` rule is trying to tell you this.

Comment: please try to understand that the code was just to explain my question. I could not explain it simply in words. This does not mean I am literally following the same code in my application....:(\

Comment: @Cool_Coder: I understand that it was a contrived testcase and you were right to post one, but I encourage you to take my advice and apply it now to your wider problem.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you should not store `area`. What determines what circle you are talking about is only the `radius`.

Here is what you lose if you declare `area`as a member:

- the `const` qualifier on your getter function, as you noted.
- CPU <-> memory IO, as you are systematically trying to update the area in your object data whenever you're trying to read your area. Memory accesses take EONS. It is really way faster to recompute the area at every access than to fetch it from memory.
- Compactness of your memory layout. You're uselessly doubling your storage need, losing the opportunity to load twice as much of your objects into a single cache line, if you're putting your structures in a `vector`.

I know your `Circle` class is really illustrative, but try transposing this way of thinking onto your project.